# Realtime printing of what's typed

Tags: java

```
public class NewJFrame3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame3
 */
public NewJFrame3() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 100));

    jTextField1.setText("Input Here");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setEnabled(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 167, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 213, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 80, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 209, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame3().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

what should I write under my actionlistener so that what's typed in the textfield gets printed in the textfield on the right side in REAL-TIME? for example if i type 123BC on the textfield on the left, it gets printed in the right side without pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
// Listen for changes in the text
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }

  public void warn() {
     if (Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())<=0){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
          "Error: Please enter number bigger than 0", "Error Massage",
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to attach a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to your textfield. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) tutorial for more information.

Comment: why not just upvote the existing answer that proposes this? :P

Comment: This answer contains additional info (java doc and complete usage example) that might be helpful in understanding better.